# async_generator garbage collected in python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-asyncio, telethon

I use [telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) library to work with telegram clients. When I get an iterator on messages, I get below error after reading all message from a chat (i.e., reading history completed):

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method AsyncGenerator.__del__ of <async_generator._impl.AsyncGenerator object at 0x7f2cbdc54f60>>

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/ahmad/PycharmProjects/thelethontest/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/async_generator/_impl.py", line 324, in __del__
.format(self._coroutine.cr_frame.f_code.co_name)

RuntimeError: partially-exhausted async_generator 'iter_messages' garbage collected
```

Why do I get this error and how can solve this?

---

i understand this error occur when use `break` in for loop. i need break loop in some condition. i need a solution to break loop without getting error.

Comment: Can we please have the **full** error traceback?

Comment: @FHTMitchell read again my question. i add full error traceback and some note. thanks.

Comment: Are you closing your async generator? If you're not already doing so, make sure you use [`aclosing`](https://pypi.org/project/async_generator/1.5/#aclosing), i.e. spell out the full `async with aclosing(some_async_gen()) as gen: for item in gen` in every place where you currently do only `async for item in some_async_gen(): ...`. This should properly close the generator and even when `break` is used to break iteration before the generator is exhausted.